# Mysql stored procedure too slow

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures

I have written a  stored procedure in my sql which is very slow. there are million records in database .

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `FetchEnergyLine`(IN From_Time INT, IN
    To_Time INT, IN Meter_Id INT, IN Device_Id VARCHAR(10), IN ct INT)
BEGIN
DECLARE c INT(5) default 0;
DECLARE Count INT default 1;

SET autocommit=0; 
SET @c=0;
SET Count = (SELECT COUNT(TimeStamp) FROM Meter_Data
WHERE 
    TimeStamp > From_Time
    AND TimeStamp < To_Time 
    AND MeterID = Meter_Id 
    AND DeviceID = Device_Id );

IF Count > (2*ct) THEN SET Count=Count/ct;
ELSE SET COUNT = 20;
END IF;

SELECT * FROM ( SELECT TimeStamp, FwdHr, W , @c:=@c+1  as counter
FROM 
    Meter_Data
WHERE 
    TimeStamp > From_Time
    AND TimeStamp < To_Time 
    AND MeterID = Meter_Id 
    AND DeviceID = Device_Id ORDER BY TimeStamp
) as tmp
WHERE
counter % Count =1; 
END
```

i think when i had less data it was very fast but my other queries with same database are running fine but stored procedure is slow. 
1) it can be count statement which is counting number of readings in beginning but i am not too sure.

Can anybody help?? thanks in advance..

Comment: What does the execution plan says ?

Comment: Sounds like you probably need an index or two.

Comment: i am new with my sql . what is execution plan ? where can i see that?

Comment: @InderpalSingh It's in my answer.

Comment: Do you have a composite index on `(MeterID, DeviceID, Timestamp)` ?

Comment: @twoleggedhorse how to do indexes? is there any alternative of that count part? should i index timestamp also?

Comment: @eggyal no i don't have. i am using this combo as primary key. but other simple query other than stored proc is running fine without index

Comment: @eggyal i have this as primary key

Comment: @eggyal now whats this? do primary key is automatically indexed before?

Comment: Indexes and keys are the same thing.  The `PRIMARY KEY` is therefore an index.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31673/discussion-between-inderpal-singh-and-eggyal)

Comment: Why are we focusing on Indexes here? The problem seems to be that the query is running row by row. I could be mistaken as I'm not a mySQL guy.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I do after building my query is making sure I didn't forget anything. (Indexes, temporary tables, keys etc...)

At first look, I would guess you have some table scans in your plan which could take 80-90% of the process time.
To make sure it doesn't happen, create the required [indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html) in the tables you query.

To make sure nothing is taking *too long*, you should study how to use the [execution plan](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html) and see what takes the longest.